# Merging two Heaps of different Sizes

Tags: java, heap, binary-search-tree

This is a somewhat homework question and somewhat not.  In my homework I had to demonstrate how to merge two Heaps of the same size and estimate it's time complexity.  While I was searching for this I read about skew Heaps and the Fibonacci Heap.

My question is, can you combine two heaps of separate sizes to one heap?  With all the examples I found online I couldn't get a straight answer from it.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: Did you check this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595333/merge-heaps-algorithm

Comment: I'm sorry.  I didn't see that thread. Will check now, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take an array of size M+N : where M is the size of first array and N is the size of second array. Now **insert** all the elements into that array and hepify it. 
Time complexity would be O((m+n)log(m+n)){as each hepify operation takes log(m+n) and we have m+n elements} + the complexity of the **insert** operation: Theta(m)+Theta(n) + O((m+n)log(m+n))