# Merging heaps implemented as sorted arrays

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, heap

When we have two binary min heaps implemented as doubly sorted linked links , what's the most efficient algorithm regarding the worst-case time to merge one heap into another ,

What I though myself, is that I would insert the elements of the heap with smaller number of elements in to the heap with larger number of elements :

If I have random access to elements (Which is usually not the case with linked list) it would be done in `O(m * log(n+m))` where `m < n` because I can insert each element of smaller heap into the larger heap, otherwise it would be `O(m * n)` because I have to insert each element in to the least of already sorted list.

Is there any other idea that works faster and have better worst time ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in O(m + n) time easily, so long as you are able to keep track of which node you are examining in a traversal of the heap.  In pseudo-code:

```
Iterator iterDest = largerHeap.getIterator();
Iterator iterSrc = smallerHeap.getIterator();

while (iterSrc.hasMore()) {
    valueSrc = iterSrc.getCurrent();
    valueDest = iterDest.getCurrent();

    if (valueSrc <= valueDest) {
        // Insert elements in their proper place in largerHeap
        iterDest.insertBeforeCurrent(valueSrc);
        iterSrc.moveNext();
    } else {
        if (iterDest.hasMore()) {
            iterDest.moveNext();
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}

// Append extra elements to the end of largerHeap
while (iterSrc.hasMore()) {
    largerHeap.append(iterSrc.getCurrent());
    iterSrc.moveNext();
}
```

Comment: And what if it's implemented as unsorted doubly linked list with distinct members ? Does the distinction really help in terms of order of worst-case time in that case ? 


Well, a good algorithm is suggested here : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595333/merge-heaps-algorithm

but does the distinction affect the time ?

Comment: The algorithm I've provided will not work if the linked lists are unsorted.  You'd be far better off using a hash set or some other structure for detecting duplication in the unsorted case.