# Merging two min-heaps implemented as doubly unsorted linked lists with distinct members

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, linked-list, heap

Let's assume that we want to merge two min-heaps implemented as arrays while the members are all distinct, what's the most efficient algorithm in terms of worst-case time to implement this merge ?

There's a good answer to the same case without 'distinction' condition , here : 
[Algorithm for merging two max heaps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595333/merge-heaps-algorithm)

But how does the distinction can help us to have a better running time algorithm ?

Comment: Question is edited now

Comment: I've reworded this question to remove the word "unsorted."  I think that this ends up being more confusing than was intended.  It's not that the elements are unsorted as much as they're ordered as a min-heap, which are two totally different conditions.