# Algorithm of merging two heaps (at different sizes)

Tags: algorithm, merge, heap, big-o

I saw this question:
[Algorithm for merging two max heaps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595333/algorithm-for-merging-two-max-heaps)  and I want to add something -   The max-heaps are at different size...

So my question is - If we have two max-heaps A and B that have a and b elements, and we know that the smallest element at A is bigger from the root (the biggest element) of B - **How we can make a one max-heap at O(b)?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the smallest element in max-heap A is larger than the largest element in max-heap B, then you can append B to A (O(b) operation) and then reconstruct the max-heap for the B section of the array. Heap construction is an O(n) operation and because every element in A is greater than every element in B so the heap reconstruction in B will never update any element in A. So overall it should still be an O(b) operation.

Comment: I don't think is correct, because think about this: `A=[30], B=[20,19,6,18,17,5,4,15,14,13,12,3,2]`